# How to add a custom block or template to specific 2columns-left layout only

Tags: magento2, layout, update-handle, landing-pages

We are trying to add newsletter template to pages that are only have 2columns-left layout, for that we have created a custom module and added below code, but it seems it is not working. Can any one tell help us, what could be the issue.

app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\default.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
            <body>
            <referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
        <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Comment: Have you checked it with 2colums-left layout?

Comment: I have added layout="2columns-left" into page tag. i have not tried with 2columns-left.xml

Comment: I mean have you check output in 2 column layout like category page?

Comment: It is coming every page regardless of any layout, but i want to call pages that are only having 2columns-left

Comment: You can see it's out put on only 2 column left layout.

Comment: I have checked your code for 2columns-left and it's working. not showing all page. Can you please check again after remove var/cache foleder.

Comment: I am sure, the block is loading even in home page too which is page-layout-1column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a custom container within your 2columns-left.xml within your theme and assign your custom block to this new container within your theme default.xml ?

**UPDATE:**

Add the following to add a custom container to your layout xml

> [your-theme]/Magento_Theme/page_layout/2columns-left.xml

```
 <container name="newsletter.section" as="newsletter_section" label="Newsletter Section"/>
```

Add your .phtml to the container in your theme default.xml

> [your-theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="newsletter.section">
    <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="newsletter" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml"></block>
</referenceContainer>
```

If you haven't got these xml files within your theme you will need to duplicate them from the vendor folder.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Can you please tell us a little bit more on how to add.

Comment: I've updated my answer for you :)

Comment: No worries, I'm glad its working for you ;)